# Two draggables and two droppables on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have two set of draggable and two sets of dropable elements.

What I want is the first set of draggable elements to be droppable only inside the first set of droppables.
The second set of draggables should be droppable only to inside the second set of droppables.

A code snippet:

```
// this can be dropped only inside .drop elements
$('.drag').draggable({ revert: true });
$('.drop').droppable({
    drop: function() {
        //          
   }
});

// this can be dropped only inside .drop2 elements
$('.drag2').draggable({ revert: true });
$('.drop2').droppable({
    drop: function() {
        //          
   }
});
```

So a user won't be able to drop element with .drag class to .drop2 container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`This`**](http://jsfiddle.net/9yb8y/) is what you want.

Use [`Accept`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-accept) property of droppable widget and [`revert`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-revert) property of draggable widget to achieve this.

Comment: One more question. What if I had only one droppable container. How would I find out, which draggable element got dragged there?

Comment: Modify your drop function to                                          drop: function(event, ui) {
        alert( $(ui.draggable).attr("id")  )
        $( this ).html( "Dropped!" );
    }

Comment: With ui.draggable you can get id of item being dropped.